# open python script in virtualenv from python script

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I want to open a python script from an other python scrip but in the virtualenv 
I tried `os.system` and `subprocess.call` but they couldn't open the virtualenv

```
os.system("workon cv") warning:

sh: 1: workon: not found

cmd = 'workon cv'

subprocess.call(cmd.split())     error:

    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: you could wrap it in a module, place the module in the script folder or add the path to the module to the python path and import it.

Comment: Have you tried adding the full path to the 'workon' binary ? Or if it's an alias for something else like virtualenv activate then do os.system('/usr/bin/virtualenv activate cv') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

1. the python script where I want to call the other python script should be opened in the virtualenv
2. put all the code in main function and import the file: `import FileName`

then call the main function: `FileName.main()`

Answer (score 1):

`workon` is not a program but a shell function from `virtualenvwrapper`. You cannot call it in a subprocess because it changes the current shell environment.